# Exact Target Amp Script Triggered Send There Are No Valid Subscribers

Tags: exacttarget

Ampscript post returns no valid users.Any ideas? This is an enterprise account and exact target is not very help full. I created a api call and tried server side js but that returns with even worse response.

```
%%[

var @emailaddr
SET @emailaddr = 'email@gmail.com'
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_subkey = 'email@gmail.com'

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "ET_Support_LS")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @emailaddr)  
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)

SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "Subscriber Key")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", @ts_subkey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_attr)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)
 ]%%
```

Answer (score 3):

Enterprise accounts in ExactTarget have sub-accounts that are called "On Your Behalf" Accounts. Anytime a subscriber is added to an account or sent an email using TriggeredSend, a value needs to be passed to specify which sub-account they are related to.  With a TriggeredSend, this can be accomplished by setting the ChannelMemberID field in the attributes of a subscriber.  A list of the sub-accounts can be found in the ExactTarget UI by going to the Admin tab, then 'Enterprise Management' then 'Organizational Chart'.

Code that needs to be added:

```
SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "ChannelMemberID")
SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", "PUT THE NUMERIC VALUE FOR AN OYB ACCOUNT HERE")
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
```

Full Example:
    %%[

```
var @emailaddr
SET @emailaddr = 'email@gmail.com'
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_subkey = 'email@gmail.com'

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "ET_Support_LS")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @emailaddr)  
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)  

SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "ChannelMemberID")
SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", "PUT THE NUMERIC VALUE FOR AN OYB ACCOUNT HERE")
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)
 ]%%
```

Also, it isn't necessary to pass the Subscriber Key value twice so the following section was removed from the example:

```
SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "Subscriber Key")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", @ts_subkey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @ts_attr)
```

For ExactTarget specific questions, please check out the Code@ Q&A Section at https://code.exacttarget.com/questions/newest